# Offline installation and setting Tikione Netbean Plugin

Tags: java, testing, plugins, netbeans-8, jacoco

I try to install Tikione JaCoCo Netbean plugin with *.nbm files download to :

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/tikione-jacocoverage

I have restarted my netbean but i can't see  code coverage options in my netbean menu. I work on a java project using maven.

Could you explain me how setup this plugin with an existing project using maven build tool ?

Comment: Have you read this: https://netbeans.org/kb/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/tikione-jacocoverage) states:

> [TikiOne JaCoCoverage is a] NetBeans module that provides JaCoCo code
>   coverage for **Ant based** Java SE.

There's also a [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenCodeCoverage) how to use it with Maven:

Install the **Maven Test Coverage** plugin.

> In NetBeans 7.2, JaCoCo is supported as a code coverage engine, since
>   Cobertura does not work with JDK 7 language constructs. Usage is
>   essentially the same as for Cobertura; you just need to configure
>   JaCoCo as per its recommendations:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```